# Rails - moving code from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

This is a sort of a "best practice" question but even if its not a good practice, I'd still like to know the implications of doing this type of coding - in terms of usability, scalability

according to http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/24-move-code-into-controller

you should not instantiate a variable from the view, but do it in the controller first

so instead of `<% @posts = Post.find(:all) %>`
it should be     `@posts = Post.find(:all)` in the corresponding controller

when running rails best practice gem on my code I got that error on a line that looks like

```
 <% @msgs_by_sender.keys.each do |uid| %>
 <% @user = User.find(uid) %>
```

which basically `uid` is the a user_id taken from the array of a previously calculated array in the controller. Then once I get the uid I get the @user so it's easier to work with

My question is - since I know this code works and nothing exploded, I don't mind leaving it as it is. But are there any long term advantages to having instead this kind of line

```
@users = User.find(@msgs_by_sender.keys)
```

Comment: In first case code casts a number of sql calls. In second it is only one sql call. Isn't it an advantage?

Answer (score 0):

The original post you cited doesn't say "never instantiate a variable in a view", but what the best practice says is "not to include *logic* in the view". The purpose of the view is to display data. Logic should be in the controller or the model depending upon the type of logic it is. This is part of the MVC philosophy which, in the long run, helps keep your code more scalable and maintainable. The view may need to assign a local variable to help with details of the view, like choosing which class to use on a display element depending upon a data value. There is such thing as "view logic" which belongs in the view. If it's a little elaborate, the convention is to use a "helper" function which would go into the helpers folder.